# Paint Speed and Use Visual Styles On Windows And Buttons

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been working on a winforms project that has quite a few controls. I've been going back and forth enabling doublebuffering or enabling composite style on several of the user controls, but no matter what I do, the refresh rate is terrible; I get a lot of white sections as I drag other windows over the top.

But if I go into System > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > Performance settings > Enable "Use Visual Styles On Windows And Buttons", the problem is fixed.

I'm calling Application.EnableVisualStyles() in program.cs.

I've been unable to research why I can't get it to paint without tearing without this option on.

What is it that "Use Visual Styles On Windows And Buttons" is applying, that isn't active without it?

Comment: Hard to guess, this question is asked 8 years too late.  Aero fixed this artifact and nobody tinkers with that option anymore.  Time for a machine and OS update perhaps.